# are longer #include paths ever actually needed?

Tags: c++

For example, if I had a file called foo.h, can I always just include it by doing:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

or do I sometimes have to do something like:

```
#include "bar/foobar/foo.h"
```

EDIT - are they simply used to make the compile time shorter by limiting the search for the file?

Comment: You seem to assume that the compiler will search subdirectories if it doesn't find the file in any of the include directories. What makes you think that?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can pass include paths as options to the C++ compiler, but it won't look for the file recursively. If you pass in the path `/opt/include` and do "`#include "foo.h"`, it will _ only_ find `/opt/include/foo.h`, not `/opt/include/dummy/foo.h`.

In other words, either you pass every possible include path on the command line, or pass the root in and "navigate" by using the `#include "dummy/foo.h"`

Edit: @MatthieuM. made another good point below, `#include "mylibrary/api.h"`makes it much clearer which include file you're using than just `#include "api.h"`, especially if you're using multiple libraries.

Comment: Personal note: I prefer to navigate by hand, makes it easier to see from where a particular include is coming from.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, same here, `#include "mylibrary/api.h"` beats `#include "api.h"` any day for readability.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler isn't going to recursively search your source directory. If you want to use `#include "foo.h"`, you'll need to compile with `-Ibar/foobar` to tell the compiler it should look in `bar/foobar` for header files.

Otherwise, you'll have to use the full (relative) path. I tend to prefer this over `-I`, because it makes the source more independent from compiler flags (which you'll appreciate when changing between build systems).

Answer (score 0):

There may be cases where there are multiple header files with the same name - in this case, a path helps to disambiguate.

Comment: yeah that's what I have now. how to write these simple paths and what they mean is actually something I've never learned. What do I google to find out about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends of your project settings, for example you have section like "Additional Include Directories" in Visual C++ so IDE will also search files in these directories.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement #include "foo.h" will search for foo.h in the current working directory or in the directories mentioned under additional include directories.

If your header file is in some other path you need to explicitly mention it.

Comment: so the normal #include will search the same directory the current file is in and... backwards..? I'm a little confused on this.

Comment: My understanding is that the compiler will move 2 levels up and try to find bar directory. Then inside it will check for the foo directory and then foo.h